# Parallel processing in perl

Tags: perl

I am using the following code to run the multiprocessing jobs. After launching the multiprocessing I am trying to grep "RUN COMPLETED" from the result file, but the grep operation is completed before it reached "RUN COMPLETED" line.Hence my grep output is not correct.
However , if I use sleep(20); after $pm->wait_all_children; the grep output is correct. Can anyone let me know how to wait until my all jobs are complete, so that I can get rid of sleep(20).
I think I need to wait until my job is completely executed to generate the result file completely but unable to understand how to do it. Please suggest.

```
pJobs:
foreach my $test(sort (@test_files)) {
    $pm->start and next pJobs;
    my $Exec = $output."/Runsets/".$test;
    system ("chmod +x $Exec");
    print $LOG `lsf_bsub -J $test -o $output/Runsets/output.file < $Exec`, "\n";
    $pm->finish;
    }
    $pm->wait_all_children;
my $DH = IO::Dir->new("$output/Runsets") || die "ERROR : Can not access $output/Runsets: ($!)";
while ( defined (my $file = $DH->read)) {
    if($file =~ /^testcase\.(\d+)/) {
        my $Result_File = IO::File->new ("$output/Runsets/$file", 'r') || die "ERROR while tryed to open $output/Runsets/$file:($!)";
        grep {
            my $line = $_;
            chomp $line;
            if($line =~ /RUN COMPLETED/) {
                print $OUT "FOUND"
            }elsif ($line =~ /^ERROR:/) {
                print "ERROR - NOT FOUND";
            } 
        } <$Result_File> ;
        $Result_File->close;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please include a complete example.

Comment: yes, more code please.  what is "the result file"?  nothing you show actually outputs anything

Comment: Is your actual code doing something other than `chmod`? This, as it stands, doesn't make much sense.  There is absolutely no reason to run `grep` on all lines if all you want is to check the file for a phrase, it is very confusing to look at `grep` in void context, and it is inefficient. Just read line by line.

Comment: Sorry I missed the line  in the code. Have updated it now.

Comment: Hi @simbalque and all. Can you help me understand how to add callback to my code so that it preforms grep only after the result file is completely generated.

Comment: There isn't enough shown. Guesses: (1) `lsf_bsub` forks processes on its own, which finish later, after `lsf_bsub` itself exited. There is no easy answer to that  (2) Something is up with `$LOG` filehandle, which you never close. Add `close $LOG;`, say after you wait out all children. Btw, how does that logging work for you? The writes from child processes in general overlap. Consider each child writing its own log (and assemble them afterwards) // Otherwise, after `wait_all_children` it should all be done. You don't need callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only thing you are doing in your multiprocessing code is changing the permissions of the files to give them execute privileges--you aren't actually running the tests.  So, `wait_all_children` is only waiting for the file permissions to change--not for the tests to complete.

---

I could not duplicate your problem with `wait_all_children()`, but you can use callbacks that will execute when a child process terminates, which is nice because then you can start processing a file without having to wait until *all* the children have finished executing:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my %prog_names = (
    'a.pl' => 'a.txt',
    'b.pl' => 'b.txt',
    'c.pl' => 'c.txt',
    'd.pl' => 'd.txt',
);

my $max_procs = 3;
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($max_procs);

sub process_file {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident) = @_;

    say "** $ident just got out of the pool ".
        "with PID $pid and exit code: $exit_code";

    open my $INFILE, '<', $prog_names{$ident};
    my @lines = grep {$_ =~ /hello/} <$INFILE>;
    close $INFILE;    
    say for @lines;
}

$pm->run_on_finish(\&process_file);

PROG_NAME:
for my $prog_name (keys %prog_names) {

    system("chmod a+x $prog_name");

    #The arg for start() becomes $ident in the callback function
    my $pid = $pm->start($prog_name) and next PROG_NAME;

    # This code is the child process:
    system("/usr/bin/env perl $prog_name");

    #A numeric arg specified for finish() becomes $exit_code in the
    #callback function.
    $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

a.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

sleep int(rand(10));

open my $OUTFILE, '>', 'a.txt'; 
say {$OUTFILE} "hello a.txt world";
close $OUTFILE;
```

b.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

sleep int(rand(10));

open my $OUTFILE, '>', 'b.txt'; 
say {$OUTFILE} "hello b.txt world";
close $OUTFILE;
```

c.pl and d.pl:

```
Similar to others.
```

Output:

```
$ rm [a-d].txt
remove a.txt? y
remove b.txt? y
remove c.txt? y
remove d.txt? y

$ perl 1.pl 
** c.pl just got out of the pool with PID 23293 and exit code: 0
hello c.txt world

** b.pl just got out of the pool with PID 23290 and exit code: 0
hello b.txt world

** a.pl just got out of the pool with PID 23296 and exit code: 0
hello a.txt world

** d.pl just got out of the pool with PID 23299 and exit code: 0
hello d.txt world

$ cat [a-d].txt
hello a.txt world
hello b.txt world
hello c.txt world
hello d.txt world
```